# How to get username in Django

Tags: python, django

I need to get the username to show it in

```
<li>
    <a tabindex="-1" href="base_pages_profile.html">
       <i class="si si-user pull-right"></i>
            <span class="badge badge-success pull-right"></span>USERNAME
    </a>
</li>
```

I have tried using request.user.username and request.get_username and this does not work, is there any other way to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything you want to access inside the template you need to pass in the context. So in your view you would have something like

```
def someview(request):
    template = loader.get_template('someview.html')
    context = {
        'username': request.user.username,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

and in your template you can have

`<span class="badge badge-success pull-right"></span>{{ username }}`

Alternatively you can use context processors to expose request or user or both to the templates by default
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#context-processors

Answer (score 4):

Ensure your request user is an authenticated user. An anonymous user is used if the user is not authenticated, in which case, username is not present.

**If you can include your view and the full template in your example it would help to better answer your question.**

**Tip:** Inspect `request.user.pk` to see if the user actually exists. `request.user.is_anonymous` and `request.user.is_authenticated` are also available.

### Reference:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Django's built-in user management, make sure it is [properly installed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/#installation).

Particularly, in your settings, you should have at least:

- `'django.contrib.auth'` in `INSTALLED_APPS`
- `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'` in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`
- `'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth'` in your template engine's context processors

If you have created your django project with [`django-admin startproject`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-startproject), [all of these should already be in place](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/project_template/project_name/settings.py-tpl)

Answer (score 1):

Just wondering maybe this is what you need if your view function argument include 'request', eg, you want to show the user who login:

```
 <span class="badge badge-success pull-right"></span>{{ request.user }}
```